# How to import external package symbols with excluding some

Tags: package, common-lisp, name-conflict

In a new package I want to `:use` (inherit from) package `packa` and `packb`.

`packa` and `packb` have an intersection of exported symbols.

How is it possible to inherit all from `packa` but only those of `packb` that are not intersecting with `packa`?

UPDATE:

I've tried `:use` `packa` and selectively `:import-from` symbols from `packb` that I need and don't collide with `packa`. However that's quite combersome.

I've experimented a bit with `do-external-symbols` and `intern`/`import`, but that doesn't seem to work, or at least I don't know how it could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadowing is the way to avoid conflicts in this case.

If you want to use symbols from packa without a prefix, use `:shadowing-import-from #:packa #:sym1 #:sym2 ...` in your package definition. Or, use packb if you prefer those symbols without a prefix.

If you prefer to use prefixes for all of the conflicting symbols from both packages, use `:shadow #:sym1 #:sym2 ...` instead.

Comment: CLHS MAKE-PACKAGE says: "In situations where the packages to be used contain symbols which would conflict, it is necessary to first create the package with :use '(), then to use shadow or shadowing-import to address the conflicts, and then after that to use use-package once the conflicts have been addressed."

Comment: Yes, if you are in a situation where you must use MAKE-PACKAGE, that's the way to go. (This isn't very common, is it?)

Comment: one maybe wants to compute the conflicting symbols, instead of writing them down. why not use make-package then?

Comment: I'm using `:shadow`. Works fine in my situation. Though this `conduit-packages` library with ':extends/including' / 'excluding' is semantically nicer.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by 'an intersection of exported symbols' what you mean is that the two packages have an intersection of exported symbol *names*, not the symbols themselves (see below).  So, for instance, I assume the packages are defined something like this:

```
(defpackage :p1
  (:use)
  (:export #:s1 #:s2))

(defpackage :p2
  (:use)
  (:export #:s2 #:s3))
```

Which means that both `P1` and `P2` export a symbol named `"S2"` but `(eq 'p1:s2 'p2:s2)` is false.

In this case you can't use both `P1` and `P2`.  You can massage things by explicitly importing (or `shadowing-import`ing) symbols but generally that's quite undesirable, not to mention messy.

A good approach in this case is to define a *conduit* package, which is a package which simply acts as a conduit between you and one or more implementation packages, reexporting symbols as needed.  The simplest approach is to use a pre-canned way of creating conduit packages such as [Tim Bradshaw's 'conduit-packages' system](https://tfeb.github.io/conduit-packages/), available in Quicklisp.  (Some tentacle of ASDF also has a similar system I think but I am not familiar with that one.)  This provides an extended variant of `defpackage` which does what you need.

Using this system, and with the above package definitions, you might say this to create a conduit:

```
(define-conduit-package :p3
  (:use)
  (:extends :p1)
  (:extends/excluding :p2 #:s2))
```

This new package `P3` now reexports the symbols from `P1` and `P2`, except for `P2:S2`:

```
 (use-package :p3)
t

> (symbol-package 's1)
#<The P1 package, 0/16 internal, 2/16 external>

> (symbol-package 's2)
#<The P1 package, 0/16 internal, 2/16 external>

> (symbol-package 's3)
#<The P2 package, 0/16 internal, 2/16 external>
```

You can obviously provide more than one symbol name to exclude, and you can pick and choose: assume you now have

```
(defpackage :p1
  (:use)
  (:export #:s1 #:s2 #:s3)

(defpackage :p2
  (:use)
  (:export #:s2 #:s3 #:s4))

(define-conduit-package :p3
  (:use)
  (:extends/excluding :p1 #:s3)
  (:extends/excluding :p2 #:s2))
```

Then, this time without using `P3` to make it easier to see:

```
> '(p3:s1 p3:s2 p3:s3 p3:s4)
(p1:s1 p1:s2 p2:s3 p2:s4)
```

You can also define conduits which extend packages only *including* certain symbol names, for instance:

```
(define-conduit-package :p4
  (:use)
  (:extends/including :p1 #:s1)
  (:extends/excluding :p2 #:s1))
```

will tell it to reexport only the symbol named `"S1"` from `P1`, and not to reexport any symbol with this name from `P2`.

Finally you can of course define conduits with functions.  For instance:

```
(defun make-conduit-package-excluding (n for-package/s excluding-from-package/s)
  ;; extend FOR-PACKAGE/S, excluding exports from EXCLUDING-FROM-PACKAGE/S
  (let ((conduit (make-package n :use '()))
        (excluders (if (listp excluding-from-package/s)
                       (mapcar #'find-package excluding-from-package/s)
                     (list (find-package excluding-from-package/s)))))
    (dolist (p (if (listp for-package/s)
                    (mapcar #'find-package for-package/s)
                  (list (find-package for-package/s)))
               conduit)
      (do-external-symbols (s p)
        (let ((sn (symbol-name s)))
          (unless (some (lambda (excluder)
                        (multiple-value-bind (ss status) (find-symbol sn excluder)
                          (and (eq status ':external)
                               (not (eq ss s)))))
                      excluders)
          (import s conduit)
          (export s conduit)))))))
```

Now if I say (using the most recent definitions of `P1` and `P2` above:

```
> (make-conduit-package-excluding "P5" "P1" "P2")
#<The P5 package, 0/16 internal, 1/16 external>

> (use-package "P5")
t

> (use-package "P2")
t
```

Everything is again OK because I told the function that `P5` should not reexport any symbols from `P1` which would clash with `P2`'s exports.

---

**A note on 'intersection of exported symbols'.**  If you have two packages which export some of *the same symbols* rather than *different symbols with the same names*, then there is no issue using both.  For example:

```
(defpackage :cl-re-1
  (:use :cl)
  (:export #:defpackage))


(defpackage :cl-re-2
  (:use :cl)
  (:export #:defpackage))
```

Then

```
> 'cl-re-1:defpackage
defpackage

> 'cl-re-2:defpackage
defpackage

> (use-package :cl-re-1)
t

> (use-package :cl-re-2)
t
```

Comment: It's neither undesirable nor messy to use shadowing to control how symbols are found. It's standard.

Comment: @Xach: standards can also be ugly, undesirable, fragile, hacks.  Better standards can be created if people will only try.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. The library ('conduit-packages') looks great. Semantically I like this better than the `:shadow` approach.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is because you don't want to manually write down
all the overlapping functions - you could let a function write it down for you.

Let's say in a setting of:

```
(defpackage :p1
  (:use :cl)
  (:export #:s1 #:s2 #:s3))

(in-package :p1)

(defconstant s1 1)
(defconstant s2 2)
(defconstant s3 3)

(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage :p2
  (:use :cl)
  (:export #:s2 #:s3 #:s4))

(in-package :p2)

(defconstant s2 "b")
(defconstant s3 "c")
(defconstant s4 "d")

(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage :p3
  (:use :cl :p1 :p2)
  (:shadowing-import-from :p1 #:s2 #:s3)
  (:export #:s1 #:s2 #:s3 #:4))

(in-package :p3)

;; package local nicknames
;; https://gist.github.com/phoe/2b63f33a2a4727a437403eceb7a6b4a3

(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage :p4
  (:use #:cl #:p1 #:p2)
  (:shadowing-import-from #:p2 #:s2 #:s3)
  (:export #:s1 #:s2 #:s3 #:s4))

(defpackage #:p5
  (:use #:cl-user)
  (:export #:s2 #:s3 #:s4))
```

I prefer to use uninterened keywords ("#:") to not to "pollute" the KEYWORD package's content.

One could then define the helper functions:

```
(defun make-uninterned-keyword (name)
  "String to Uninterned Keyword"
  (read-from-string (format nil "#:~a" name)))

(defun make-keyword (name)
  "String to Keyword"
  (values (intern (string-upcase name) "KEYWORD")))

(defun get-symbols (package)
  "Return all symbols of a package 
   (`package` should be a string)"
  (let (symbols)
     (do-external-symbols (s (find-package (string-upcase package)))
       (push s symbols))
    (nreverse (mapcar #'symbol-name symbols))))
;; (lambda (s) (read-from-string (format nil "#:~a" (symbol-name s))))

(defun %overlapping-symbols (package-1 package-2)
  "Determine symbols overlapping between the packages"
  (let ((symbols-1 (get-symbols package-1))
        (symbols-2 (get-symbols package-2)))
    (intersection symbols-1 symbols-2 :test #'string=)))

(defun overlapping-symbols (package &rest packages)
  "Determine symbols overlapping from first package with the rest of the packages"
  (remove-duplicates (loop for pkg in packages
                           nconcing (%overlapping-symbols package pkg))
                     :test #'string=))

(defun generate-shadowing-import-form (package &rest packages)
  "Construct code for shadowing-import-from"
  (let* ((overlapping-symbols (apply #'overlapping-symbols package packages))
         (overlapping-keywords (mapcar #'make-uninterned-keyword overlapping-symbols)))
    `(:shadowing-import-from ,(make-uninterned-keyword package) ,@overlapping-keywords)))

(defun shadowing-import-string (package &rest packages)
  "Construct string for :shadowing-import-from directive"
  (string-downcase (format nil "~s" (apply #'generate-shadowing-import-form package packages))))
```

So by running:

```
(shadowing-import-string "P2" "P1" "P5")
;; => "(:shadowing-import-from #:p2 #:s2 #:s3 #:s4)"
```

You get the piece of code you want to copy paste into your
`DEFPACKAGE` definition. Any symbol in the `:p2` package which overlaps with the `:p1` and/or the `:p5` package is then listed.